# How to restart eclipse's tomcat server using java codes

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm working on a project which is writing ms access datas in ms word document. When I run this project more than once, it overwrites word document like this images.

[image: the first run everything is ok]

[image: but second run it overwrites on first run]

At the first time I'm running the project everthing is ok, but second time it overwrites on first one. I thought if I restart the server or application , problem will be solved. To do this I wrote this codes

```
try {
            Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",8080);
            if(socket.isConnected())
            {
                socket.close();
                System.out.println("Server closed");
            }

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("catalina.home")+"\\bin\\startup.bat");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
```

But it didn't work as I wanted. So I want your helps.

public static void header_footer(String SalesOrder,String type) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException
{

```
XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();   

  if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);
  XWPFTable asd= header.createTable(1, 2);
  asd.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.LEFT);
  XWPFTableRow row;
  XWPFTableCell cell,cell2;
  CTHeight ht;
  CTTrPr trPr;
  CTTblWidth cellWidth;
  row= asd.getRow(0);
  trPr = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
  ht = trPr.addNewTrHeight();
  ht.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(-1070));         
  cell=row.getCell(0);        

  XWPFParagraph parag=document.createParagraph();
  parag = cell.getParagraphArray(0);
  XWPFRun r1=parag.createRun();

    //InputStream pic = new FileInputStream(imgFile2);
    /*  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(imgFile2);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);*/
    //InputStream pic = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imgFile2));

    // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pic));
     // Image jpg = Image.getInstance("/pages/jpg/bg-header.jpg");

     /* URL imgLogoUrl = access.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
      Image imgLogo= Image.getInstance(imgLogoUrl+"../../images/logo.JPG");  
      */
  InputStream pic = access_connection.class.getResourceAsStream("page1_header.png");

  //InputStream pic = new URL(imgFile2).openStream();

  r1.addPicture(pic, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile2, Units.toEMU(160), Units.toEMU(55)); 


    cellWidth = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();            
    cellWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3500));
    cell2=row.getCell(1);
    cellWidth = cell2.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();           
    cellWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf((short)20000));


parag=cell2.getParagraphArray(0);
parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
cell2.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
XWPFRun r2=parag.createRun();
r2.setFontSize(14);
r2.setFontFamily("Calibri");
r2.setText("TURKISH ENGINE CENTER SHOP VISIT REPORT");
r2.addBreak();
r2.setText("ESN "+SalesOrder.substring(1, 7)+"                         Istanbul,TURKEY");



//  headerFooterPolicy.getFirstPageHeader().clearHeaderFooter();

XWPFParagraph paragraph = header.createParagraph();
paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);


XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  

InputStream a;
XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);
XWPFParagraph parag2= footer.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run3=parag2.createRun();
XWPFRun run4=parag2.createRun();
run3.setFontFamily("Arial");
run4.setFontFamily("Arial");
run3.setBold(true);
run4.setItalic(true);
run3.setFontSize(8);
run4.setFontSize(9);
run3.setText("U.S. Export Classification: EAR ECCN 9E991");
run3.addBreak();
run4.setText("Printed by TEC Local EVM System");
XWPFParagraph parag3= footer.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run5=parag3.createRun();
parag3.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
run5.setFontSize(7);
run5.setFontFamily("Arial");
run5.setText("Page ");
run5.getCTR().addNewPgNum();


try {


        FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(word_saveas_file+SalesOrder+"_"+type+"_Report.docx");

        document.write(input);
        input.close();  

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my header-footer codes. It's one of them that overwrited. Everytime I'm creating diffent word document because the `SalesOrder` parameter changing everytime but it still overwrites.

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you used to build the document? The problem might be located in that code. In my opinion restarting of the server probably will not help and rather is a patch than a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to launch a  batch script Programmatically :

inculde this code :

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM java.exe");
    System.exit(0);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Logger.handle(e);
}
```

here is a link to help you how to create a windows service : [http://dotnetlearners.com/windowsservice/creating-first-windows-service](http://here%20is%20a%20link%20to%20help%20you%20how%20to%20create%20a%20windows%20service%20:%20http://dotnetlearners.com/windowsservice/creating-first-windows-service)

here is how should look your Service code source via c#

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
   if (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
       File.Create(fileLocation).Close();
   File.AppendAllText(fileLocation, "Service started : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\startup.exe");
   OnStop();
  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
   File.AppendAllText(fileLocation, "Service stoped : " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
  }
```

then u call ur service after you shutdown your server via java like that

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM java.exe");
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net start servicename");
    System.exit(0);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    Logger.handle(e);
}
```

Comment: Fine, it's stopping tomcat but how can I start again tomcat after this stopping.

Comment: you are working on windows right ? you can launch a service on windows that check if tomcat is started or not whenever you kill java.exe and if tomcat is not started you start server via cmd line and stop this service all that must be in a bat file

Comment: OK, I got it and I'll try it.

Comment: hopefully that helped you to achieve what you want